# Webcrawler - Scrapy Python

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, export-to-csv, keyword, counting

I need help with my webcrawler.
I got an invalid syntax here:

```
  "f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(word,url,count))"
```

and also when I command "scrapy crawl FirstSpider > wordlist.csv" a csv file shows up but either is empty or not as structured as I want it to be.
I want to crawl 300 websites and need the data as structured as possible.
How can I get a csv file with the urls structured and then the count of the certain keywords next to it,

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item
import requests

def find_all_substrings(string, sub):

    import re
    starts = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), string)]
    return starts

class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "FirstSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

    crawl_count = 0
    words_found = 0      
                           

    def check_buzzwords(self, response):

        self.__class__.crawl_count += 1

        wordlist = [
            "keyword1",
            "keyword2",
            "keyword3"
            ]

        url = response.url
        data = response.body.decode('utf-8')
        count = 0
         
        for word in wordlist:
                substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
                count = 0
                word_counts = {}
                links = []
                "f = open('wordlist.csv', 'w')" 
                for pos in substrings:
                        ok = False
                        if not ok:
                            count += 1
                            word_counts[word] = {url: count}
                            
        for link in links:
            page = requests.get(link)
            data = page.text

        for word in wordlist:
                substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
                count = 0

        for word in wordlist:
                substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
                for pos in substrings:
                        ok = False
                        if not ok:
                                "f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(word,url,count))"
                                self.__class__.words_found += 1
                                print(word + ";" + url + ";" + str(count) + ";")
        with open('wordlist.csv', 'w') as f:
         for word, data in word_counts.items():
          for url, count in data.items():
            f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(word, url, count))
        f.close()
        return Item()

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if getattr(response, "encoding", None) != None:
                return CrawlSpider._requests_to_follow(self, response)
        else:
                return []
```

I want to crawl websites for certain keywords (wordlist). My output should be a csv file with the following information: url, count of keyword found on the website.

I got an invalid syntax for the following ```  "f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(word,url,count))"

```
And the output csv file is often empty or does not crawl all the urls.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary quotation marks around lines 41 and 61

```
line 41 ---> "f = open('wordlist.csv', 'w')"
line 61 ---> "f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(word,url,count))"
```

Also usually you don't need to manually save data to a file because Scrapy has a built-in mechanism - [Feed export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)

By using [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields) setting you can specify which fields of the item should be exported and their order.

Here is the command to run the spider and save data to a file:
`scrapy crawl FirstSpider -O url.csv`

`-O` (capital 'O') means "rewrite a file"

`-o` (lowercase 'o') means "append to an existent file".